# I'm using React using typescript with useContext and useReducer in my app, but for some reason the click won't trigger the dispatch

Tags: reactjs, typescript, dispatch

I'm having two lists displayed as cards that come from one initial list of objects.
The idea is to change the value 'favorite' in each of the cards list items when clicked on the star button, so that the items that are not faved apear in the unFaved items list and the faved apear in the faved items list.
I have a file dataContext.tsx like this:

```
import Data from './data.json'

let rawData: Bot[] = [...Data]
rawData.forEach( item => item.favorite = false )


export function createDataCtx<StateType, ActionType>(
    reducer: Reducer<StateType, ActionType>,
    initialState: StateType
) {
    const defaultDispatch: Dispatch<ActionType> = () => initialState
    const ctx = createContext({
        state: initialState,
        dispatch: defaultDispatch, // just to mock out the dispatch type and make it not optioanl
    })
    function Provider(props: PropsWithChildren<{}>) {
        const [state, dispatch] = useReducer<Reducer<StateType, ActionType>>(reducer, initialState)
        return <ctx.Provider value={{ state, dispatch }} {...props} />
    }
    return [ctx, Provider] as const
}

export const initialState = [...rawData]
type AppState = typeof initialState
type Action = 
    | { type: 'favorite', shortName: string }
    | { type: 'unFavorite', shortName: string }

export function reducer(state: AppState, action: Action): AppState {
    switch(action.shortName){
        case 'favorite':
            console.log('favorite action triggered!!')
            return state.map( (item: Bot) => item.shortName === action.shortName // will have to map the elements with the index when using it so we van pass the index
                ? {...item, favorite: true}
                : item
            )
        case 'unFavorite':
            console.log('unFavorite action triggered!!')
            return state.map( (item: Bot) => item.shortName === action.shortName // will have to map the elements with the index when using it so we van pass the index
                ? {...item, favorite: false}
                : item
            )
        default:
            return state
    }
}
```

I use my Provider like this in the app Component:

```
function App() {
  const [ , DataProvider] = createDataCtx(reducer, initialState)
  return (
    <DataProvider>
      <ThemeProvider theme={Theme}>
        <AppStyles>
          <Router>
            <Header />
            <Content />
          </Router>
        </AppStyles>
      </ThemeProvider>
    </DataProvider>
  );
}
```

And then I use the context in another component called Cards.tsx like this:

```
const [ctx, DataProvider] = createDataCtx(reducer, initialState)
const DataContext = ctx

const Cards = () => {
    
    const {state, dispatch } = useContext(DataContext)
    const faveBotsList = state.filter( item => item.favorite === true)
    const unfaveBotsList = state.filter( item => item.favorite === false )

    return (
        <CardsStyles>
            <CardsRow>
                <FavTitle>Favorites</FavTitle>
            </CardsRow>
            <FavWrap>
                {faveBotsList.map((item) => (
                    <BotCard 
                        key={item.shortName} 
                        favorite={item.favorite} 
                        name={item.name} 
                        shortName={item.shortName} 
                        onStarClick={ () => dispatch({type: 'unFavorite', shortName: item.shortName}) } 
                    />
                ))}
            </FavWrap>
            <CardsWrap>
                {unfaveBotsList.map((item) => (
                    <BotCard 
                        key={item.shortName}
                        favorite={item.favorite}
                        name={item.name}
                        shortName={item.shortName}
                        onStarClick={ () => dispatch({type: 'favorite', shortName: item.shortName}) }/>
                ))}
            </CardsWrap>
        </CardsStyles>
            
    )
}
```

Here is the "BotCard" component code if you want to see it:

```
const BotCard = (props: any) => {
    const { favorite, name, shortName, onStarClick } = props
    return (
        <StyledBCard className='col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-2'>
            <Row>
                <FavoriteStar favorite={favorite} className='float-left' onStarClick={onStarClick} />
            </Row>
            <Row className='justify-content-center'>
                <BotImage imageSrc={TestImage} />
            </Row>
            <Row>
                <BotName>{name}</BotName>
            </Row>
            <Row>
                <BotShortName>{shortName}</BotShortName>
            </Row>
        </StyledBCard>
    )
}
```

the 'onStarClick' property is passed to a child component which passes it to it's child Component where it is passed to the 'onClick' property of a styled-component button.
But the click won't trigger the dispatch.
I'm not seeing what is not correctly implemented.

Comment: Please also post the code for your `BotCard` component, it seems like it never calls its `onStarClick` method

Comment: @Taxel I just edited the post and added the `BotCard` component's code.

Comment: First off: Since you already have the `dispatch` from a `Context` - why not use `useContext` in the `<FavoriteStar>` component and pass only the title as props? Secondly, I thought the `BotCard` is the one where the `dispatch` function is actually called, all components are relevant where `dispatch`/`onStarClick` is passed/called.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you are calling the dispatch while you are passing it. This should be the correct way:

```
<BotCard 
  key={item.shortName}
  favorite={item.favorite}
  name={item.name}
  shortName={item.shortName}
  dispatch={dispatch}
/>
```

And then, call it in the child:

```
<button
  onClick={() => dispatch({type: 'favorite', shortName: item.shortName})}
>
  A button
</button>
```

Comment: following your idea, I passed the dispatch like this: ``` <BotCard key={item.shortName} favorite={item.favorite} name={item.name} shortName={item.shortName} onStarClick={ () => { dispatch({type: 'favorite', shortName: item.shortName}) } } /> ``` and then called it in the child components like this: ``` <StyledSButton className={className} onClick={() => onStarClick()} > <StyledStar src={favorite ? FullStar : EmptyStar} /> </StyledSButton> ``` But it still won't trigger. No error, nothing.

Comment: You are still calling the dispatch when you pass it in the prop... Or did you past the old version? I noticed a made a mistake in the child, I used "dispatch" instead of the name of the prop.

Comment: I'm calling the dispatch in the child component with the name of the prop, and not 'dispatch', that is `onClick={() => onStarClick()}`.
In the parent Component I am passing the dispatch like this: `onStarClick={ () => { dispatch({type: 'favorite', shortName: item.shortName}) } }`

Comment: I see I am not clear enough. You are calling the dispatch in the parent in that way and you shouldn't. What you should pass as prop is just the name "dispatch" with no calling and no argument, like this: onStarClick={dispatch}. Then you use the prop in the child as you would do with the dispatch: onClick={() => onStarClick({type: 'favorite', shortName: item.shortName})}.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in my original reducer in the 'dataContext.tsx' file

My reducer was like this:

```
type Action = 
    | { type: 'favorite', shortName: string }
    | { type: 'unFavorite', shortName: string }

export function reducer(state: AppState, action: Action): AppState {
    switch(action.shortName){
        case 'favorite':
            console.log('favorite action triggered!!')
            return state.map( (item: Bot) => item.shortName === action.shortName // will have to map the elements with the index when using it so we van pass the index
                ? {...item, favorite: true}
                : item
            )
        case 'unFavorite':
            console.log('unFavorite action triggered!!')
            return state.map( (item: Bot) => item.shortName === action.shortName // will have to map the elements with the index when using it so we van pass the index
                ? {...item, favorite: false}
                : item
            )
        default:
            return state
    }
}
```

if you look at the parameter I was passing to the switch function is `action.shortName` instead of `action.type` so it always returned the default for the switch which is the state as it already was.

Thank's to @SimoneCelli for making me think about how I was passing and triggering the dispatch, and to @Taxel for making it obvious for me that I was not using the context for what it is actually intended mainly: Not having to pass properties and funcions in a complex way involving too many components for it.

So my reducer looks like this now working correctly:

```
type Action = 
    | { type: 'favorite', shortName: string }
    | { type: 'unFavorite', shortName: string }

export function reducer(state: AppState, action: Action): AppState {
    switch(action.type){
        case 'favorite':
            console.log('favorite action triggered!!')
            return state.map( (item: Bot) => item.shortName === action.shortName // will have to map the elements with the index when using it so we van pass the index
                ? {...item, favorite: true}
                : item
            )
        case 'unFavorite':
            console.log('unFavorite action triggered!!')
            return state.map( (item: Bot) => item.shortName === action.shortName // will have to map the elements with the index when using it so we van pass the index
                ? {...item, favorite: false}
                : item
            )
        default:
            return state
    }
}
```

where I pass the correct parameter to the switch funcion.